# SciFi story about random teleportation to frozen alien planet

Tags: story-identification, novel

Can anyone help me identify what novel this might be?

From what I can remember it was about a group of human colonists who leave earth using some kind of teleportation technology with their ship. Some ships teleport into a star, black hole, or just interstellar space. But some end up in a solar system.

I can't remember why the colonists are leaving, perhaps a dying earth situation.

This story follows a ship who finds a frozen planet that has alien ruins. Some members of the ship experience some kind of telepathy? The alien structures calling out to them maybe?

I may have read this in the mid 2000s?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall the cover art?  Is the teleportation technology part of the ship?  Is it one-way or can the ships return?

Comment: Hi!
I can't remember any artwork, unfortunately.
I think it was a one-way trip, so no ship could get back home (or try another jump.)

Comment: The classic book with people in ships teleporting randomly of course is Pohl's *Gateway*, but the rest of the details don't match.

Comment: @DanielRoseman That was part of the reason I asked about ships returning. :)

Comment: Maybe something in this list? https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BlindJump